# How do you properly resolve NPM dependencies in projects that require conflicting versions?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to build the playground app for `react-native-navigation` using instructions [here](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/docs/showcases). A simple `npm install` fails because the peer dependencies have `react: "*"` and `react-native: "*"`, so today (Jan 2021) NPM tries to install `react@17.0.1`, but also tries to install `react-native@0.63.4`, which requires `react@16.13.1`. I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native-navigation@7.7.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from the root project
...
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"16.13.1" from react-native@0.63.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native@">=0.59" from @react-native-community/datetimepicker@2.6.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker
npm ERR!
```

Then I tried to resolve this by installing `react@16.13.1` in my root project, hoping that NPM would detect and use that version as a peer dependency, but then it turns out `@react-native-community/datetimepicker@2.6.2` depends on `react-native-windows@^0.6.20`, which depends on `react@16.11.0`, giving me this error instead:

```
npm ERR! Found: react@16.13.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   dev react@"16.13.1" from the root project
...
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"16.11.0" from react-native-windows@0.62.20
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker/node_modules/react-native-windows
npm ERR!   optional react-native-windows@"^0.62.0-0" from @react-native-community/datetimepicker@2.6.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker
npm ERR!     dev @react-native-community/datetimepicker@"^2.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (react-native-ui-lib)
npm ERR!
```

How do I get to the bottom of this? I was expecting everything to just work with `npm install`. What is the proper way to install a project, or is it common to have to constantly debug dependency conflicts prior to starting a project?

Comment: I tried and didn't get any error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it turns out, I was using node 15.0.x which is apparently too new. Downgrading to 14.15.1 worked.

Comment: Select an answer that solves the problem even  if the OP answers his own question.

Answer (score 0):

I too was using node 15.0.x. Downgrading to 14.x.x worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing npm install --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: Still Not working